# Django/Nginx/Gunicorn/Supervisor: internationalisation is not applied

Tags: django, nginx, internationalization, gunicorn, supervisord

I try to deploy my Django project in a remote linux server (Ubuntu)

I have followed an Openclassroom tutorial and it work except internationalisation

I have had this problem when I deployed with alwaysdata because missing lines in my settings.py

Here I checked all internationalisation settings are present (MIDDLEWARE, LANGUAGES, LOCAL_PATH) and it seems to be

I try to set absolute path to my locale files (containing internationalisation files .po) but did not change anything

but as gunicorn is running maybe change in settings;py have not been applyed ?

**architecture of my project:**

```
envs
intensetbm_app
|   intensetbm-etool
|   |   intenseTBM_eTool
|   |   |    wsgi.py
|   |   |    settings.py
|   |   |    ...
|   |   manage.py
|   |   locale
|   |   |    fr
|   |   |    |     LC_MESSAGES
|   |   |    |     |      django.po
|   |   ...
intensetbm_static
```

**settings.py:**

```
import os
import psycopg2.extensions
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.80.6',]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'bootstrap4',

    'registration.apps.RegistrationConfig',
    'monitor.apps.MonitorConfig',
    'randomization.apps.RandomizationConfig',
    'parameters.apps.ParametersConfig',

    'django_extensions',
    'debug_toolbar',

    'partial_date',
    'safedelete',
    'simple_history',

]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    **'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',**
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'randomization.middleware.stock',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'intenseTBM_eTool.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'registration/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'monitor/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),    
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'randomization.context_processors.data_context_processor',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'intenseTBM_eTool.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME':'intensetbm',
        'USER': 'intensetbm_admin',
        'PASSWORD':'******',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'registration.validators.MerevaValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Lists of languages site supports.
**LANGUAGES = (
     ('en', _('English')),
     ('fr', _('French')),
)
#LOCALE_PATHS = [
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'locale'),
#]
LOCALE_PATHS = [
        '/home/test/intensetbm_app/intensetbm-etool/locale',
]**

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'unblind/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pharmacy/static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/test/intensetbm_static'


LOGIN_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Comment: Did you run `manage.py compilemessages` after deploying? Check that the locale folders contain the *.mo* files

Comment: I have done it to bu sure and have the 2 files .mo and .po in my files fr/LC_MESSAGES but my site is still not translated

Comment: think I shloud Restart server but how to do that with ngxin/gunicorn/supervisor?

Comment: You have to restart gunicorn, yes

Comment: With `supervisorctl` you should be able to just `restart gunicorn`.

Comment: I could not find the command... I tried sudo restart intensetbm-gunicorn (which is declared i my supervisor config files but it is not recognized...

Comment: sudo supervisorctl restart intensetbm-gunicorn (I forget supervisorctl) !!!!